# Problems with JNI and C++

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, java-native-interface

I did an Opencv's application en windows and now I am using JNI to convert this code to Android but I am having some problems.
In concrete my native code not do nothing.

This is my Java class where I define my native methods:

```
package com.example.telo3;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Process {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("nativo");
    }

    public Process(){

        dir=inicializar_nativo();
    }

    public void Procesar(Mat framedetect, Mat framedraw){

        procesar_nativo(dir,framedetect.getNativeObjAddr(),framedraw.getNativeObjAddr());
    }


    private long dir;
    private static native long inicializar_nativo();
    private static native void procesar_nativo(long thiz, long framedetect, long framedraw);
```

}

This is my JNI code:

```
#include "nativo.h"
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "FaceDetector.h"
#include "Draw.h"
#include "Almacena.h"
#include "Runnable.h"



using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#include <android/log.h>

#define LOG_TAG "NATIVO"
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))

struct variables {
    Almacena almacena;
    Draw draw;
    FaceDetector face_detector;
};

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_telo3_Process_inicializar_1nativo(
        JNIEnv *, jobject) {

    long dir = (long) new variables();

    return (dir);


}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_telo3_Process_procesar_1nativo(JNIEnv *,
        jobject, jlong dir, jlong framedetect, jlong framedraw) {



Mat* telo =(Mat*)framedetect;
Mat* telo2= (Mat*)framedraw;

((variables*)dir)->almacena = ((variables*)dir)->face_detector.Detect(*telo);


 //almacena = face_detector.Detect(frame_gray);


 ((variables*)dir)->draw.Dibujar(*telo2,((variables*)dir)->almacena);


 //frame_capturado = draw.Dibujar(frame_capturado, almacena);



if( (((variables*)dir)->almacena.get_faces()).size() ==0){

    LOGD("no detecto caras");
}


}
```

I think that I use the Jni correctly but the function Detect not works correctly because when I uses this if return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple typo for me.

Your package is "com.example.telo3"
Your class is "Process"
Your function is "inicializar_nativo()"

So the c++ function has to be declared as

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_telo3_Process_inicializar_nativo(...)
```

You have declared it as

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_telo3_Process_inicializar_1nativo(...)
```

Did you get an unsatisfied link exception or such?